# How can I open new link in same tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I am having one Button in my page,
I dont have any Anchor tags in my page.

Now how can I open my new link by replacing with my old link.

Can any one suggest me how to do this.

Comment: `Now how can I open my new link by replacing with my old link.` where is you old link.. post the related codes too

Comment: honestly i dont think this could be answered.not sure what is the problem

Comment: Some one give this guy minus and close this absurd question. Actually, it's not even a question, it is just nothing. Post something we can understand.

Comment: Read my mind; gimme teh codez...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
var oldLocation = window.location;
window.location = newLocation;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location
Call a javascript function on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Your button...

```
<button class='mybutton' data-link="www.thelink.com">CLICK HERE</button>
```

The Jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.mybutton').click(function(){

var link = $(this).data('link');
window.location(link);

});

});
```

Have no idea if this is what you mean, as the question is not clear at all...